# No module named 'astropy.wcs'

Tags: python, astropy

i'm doing a python's code, and i want to use this:

```
from astropy.wcs import WCS
```

But when i run my code, i have this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'astropy.wcs'
This is my code:

```
from astropy.utils.data import get_pkg_data_filename 
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.wcs import WCS

archivo_fits=fits.open('Eurybates_sky.fits')
type(archivo_fits)
print(archivo_fits.info())
print(archivo_fits[0].header)
ra=Angle(' 06d59m31.64s')
dec=Angle('+29d56m45.5s')
RA=ra.degree
DEC=dec.degree
w=WCS('Eurybates_sky.fits')
x,y=w.all_world2pix(RA,DEC,1)
print(x,y)
```

Comment: Can you please post the full traceback you get, as well as what platform you're running on and how you installed astropy? Chances are the WCS module isn't compiled, or is for the wrong platform.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure astropy was installed in the same installation directory tree as your Python installation, open a new terminal and try: pip install astropy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).